# Redirect folder website to subdomain and remove last slash

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect
`website.fr/folder/something/` with or without **/** at the end to
`folder.website.fr/something` without **/** at the end

I use this working rule

```
 RewriteEngine On    
 RewriteRule ^(folder)\/?(.*)(\/?)$ http://folder.website.fr/$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

but I don't know how to remove the **/** at the end if present ?

Comment: Try `^(folder)/?(.*?)/?$`

Comment: Yes it is OK, thanks.